# CSS: estilo que afecte sólo a las columnas 3 a 6 (inclusive) de una tabla

Tags: css, html-tabla

Tengo una tabla HTML con distintas jerarquías y querría aplicar el mismo estilo a las columnas 3, 4, 5 y 6. Estoy probando con nth-child pero no doy con la fórmula apropiada; n+3 afecta de la tercera en adelante, pero no tengo claro cómo hacer que se detenga en la sexta.

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prueba con esto:

```
:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+6)
```

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias.